# How to save these elements read from a .txt file into an array/matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, split, txt, readlines

I have a .txt file that contains elements that look like this:

```
Smith 25 35 NC
Johnson 12 4 OH
Jones 23 14 FL
Lopez 2 7 TX
```

And I want to read the .txt file line by line, and save each of the elements (Name, number, number, state) in an array matrix or a list 4 x number_of_people , while ignoring any blank spaces. I'm trying to not use `split()` for it, but could use a "manual" form of `split()` instead, like shown below with `split1`.

```
def split1(line,delim):
    s=[]
    j=0
    for i in range (len(line)):
        if delim== line [i]:
            s.append(line[j:i])
            j=i+1
    s.append (line[j:])
    return s



f = open("Names.txt")
number_of_people = 0


#This portion is meant to go through the entire .txt file, 1 time and count how many people are listed on the file so I can make an appropiatly sized matrix, in the case of the example is 4
while True:
        file_eof = f.readline()
        if file_eof != '':
            number_of_people = number_of_people + 1
        if file_eof == '':
                break

#This portion reads through the .txt file agin and saves the names of the list
while True:
        file_eof = f.readline()
        if file_eof != '':
            split1(file_eof, '')
            #print(file_eof)
        if file_eof == '':
                print('No more names on the list')
                break


f.close()
```

I know there could be things missing here, and that's exactly what I would need help with here. If there is any "better" way of dealing with this than what I got please let me know and show me if possible.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to create an array of a specific size first. I suppose you have a background in C? How large is the file?

Here are 2 pythonic ways to read and store that information:

```py
filename = r"data.txt"

# Access items by index, e.g. people_as_list[0][0] is "Smith"
with open(filename) as f: # with statement = context manager = implicit/automatic closing of the file
    people_as_list = [line.split() for line in f] # List comprehension

# Access items by index, then key, e.g. people_as_dict[0]["name"] is "Smith"
people_as_dict = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        name, number1, number2, state = line.split() # Iterable unpacking
        person = {}
        person["name"] = name
        person["number1"] = number1
        person["number2"] = number2
        person["state"] = state
        people_as_dict.append(person)

print(people_as_list)
print(people_as_dict)
```

Output:

```
[['Smith', '25', '35', 'NC'], ['Johnson', '12', '4', 'OH'], ['Jones', '23', '14', 'FL'], ['Lopez', '2', '7', 'TX']]
[{'name': 'Smith', 'number1': '25', 'number2': '35', 'state': 'NC'}, {'name': 'Johnson', 'number1': '12', 'number2': '4', 'state': 'OH'}, {'name': 'Jones', 'number1': '23', 'number2': '14', 'state': 'FL'}, {'name': 'Lopez', 'number1': '2', 'number2': '7', 'state': 'TX'}]
```

Comment: Exactly, the reason why is because I'm used to specifying the size of the array first, if that's all redundant and not necesary to do here, then even better. Also I'm trying to stay away from using the builtin `split()` method as part of this excersice, trying to see if I can deal with this while having a manually implemented "non-builtin" `split()` function or any other kind of implementation that can achieve the same result, thank you for your response!

Comment: No worries. Writing your own version of built-in functions will definitely be slower, since the built-in versions are implemented in C, but it nevertheless can be a good learning exercise.

Comment: I just added a couple extra comments in my answer. I'd recommend checking the documentation for a few things - with statement/context managers, list comprehensions, and iterable unpacking. They're all important parts of writing pythonic code.